# Filter variable not updating in controller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Im attempting to build functionality around the length of a filter in angularjs, and although its working as it should in the view, in the controller the variable seems to stay outdated...

When I click on the div below it filters a list and calls the `filterby` function. The output of the length of the newly filtered list updates in the view correctly. However in the function itself I have a log set and it is still showing the old length when I click on the div.

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="filterby(filter.filter_type)">{{filter.filter_type}}</div>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in filtered = (events | filter:query) | orderBy:'-event_date' ">
        <span >{{event.event_date}},{{event.event_name}}, {{event.event_venue}}, {{event.event_description}} </span>
    </li>
</ul>

<br />Length of filtered items {{filtered.length}}
```

And my view....

```
        $scope.filterby = function(filterby) {
          if (filterby == 'ALL') {
            $scope.query = '';
          }
          else {
            $scope.query = filterby;

          }
          console.log($scope.filtered.length);
    };
```

My filter data:

```
        $scope.filters = [
         {'filter_type' : 'ALL'},
         {'filter_type' : 'Macnass'}
        ];
```

EDIT: Ok its not that it nots working at all, its just showing the previous value, as if its one click behind all the time, so its something to do with the fact that the variable in the view is updated after the list is made. but Im not sure how to go about insuring the variable in the controller is the latest value.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7KpqYx8gDwaaXEvGeMn?p=preview

Comment: can you setup a plunker, showing the problem...

Comment: I have added a plunker, upon doing that I can see clearly what the problem is, i.e the console.log is showing before the new filter is applied (I think), however Im unsure how to fix this. ( I should add that Im quite new to angularjs)

Comment: probably better to just  do your filtering in controller. Then you have access to original array and filtered array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Es9DJbc6m0HPMHYGXXNX?p=preview)

added below

```
$scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.events, $scope.query)
```

in $scope.filterby function

Comment: Thank you that sorted the issue!